# SQL - Finding parts that were ordered by a customer who ordered more than 2 distinct parts

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I have 4 tables:

- **customers**: cno (primary key), cname, street, zip, phone
- **orders**: ono (primary key), cno (foreign key), wno (foreign key), received, shipped
- **odetails**: ono (foreign key), pno (foreign key), qty, sfee
- **parts**: pno (primary key), pname, qoh, price, olevel

And I'm trying to find the names of parts that were ordered by a customer who ordered more than two distinct parts. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322322/using-sql-query-to-find-details-of-customers-who-ordered-x-types-of-products) thread was closest in relevance and helped me quite a bit, but I'm having trouble running my modified query, which is the following and returning null:

```
SELECT p.pname
FROM parts p
INNER JOIN odetails d ON p.pno=d.pno
INNER JOIN orders o ON d.ono=o.ono
INNER JOIN customers c ON o.cno=c.cno
GROUP BY p.pname, c.cname
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.pno)>2;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You really should decide on your database before you continue to try to make your query work.  Oracle, SQL Server, and MySQL are three different database engines.  Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: Show your test data set.

Comment: This naming strategy is too infuriating for me. I'm going to pass on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
GROUP BY p.pname, c.cname
```

To

```
GROUP BY c.cname
```

If you're grouping by `p.pname`, then `COUNT(DISTINCT p.pno)` will always return 1 *unless two `pno`'s have the same `pname`*

Comment: This won't work as you can't have a column in `GROUP BY` that is not in the `SELECT` - you will get `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

Comment: On MySQL, you can `GROUP BY` an expression that is not present in the `SELECT` clause. There is ambiguity on which DB the OP is using, however, he states that his query is returning NULL, not *throwing an error*. If you look at his query, you'll see that he has `c.cname` in the `GROUP BY`, but not in the `SELECT`, which led me to assumy MySQL. I'm not sure how sql-server or oracle treats this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Oracle since [your other question using the same tables for a different query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798720/sql-command-not-properly-ended-concerning-with-table-aliases) was an Oracle question.

Some things to consider. Can there be more than one customer who ordered more than two distinct parts? If so, do you want to return the customer names along with the ordered parts? First, get all the customers who have ordered more than two distinct parts:

```
SELECT c.cno
  FROM customers c INNER JOIN orders o
    ON c.cno = o.cno
 INNER JOIN odetails od
    ON o.ono = od.ono
 GROUP BY c.cno
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT od.pno) > 2;
```

Then get the parts they ordered:

```
WITH c1 AS (
    SELECT c.cno
      FROM customers c INNER JOIN orders o
        ON c.cno = o.cno
     INNER JOIN odetails od
        ON o.ono = od.ono
     GROUP BY c.cno
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT od.pno) > 2
)
SELECT p.pno, p.pname, COUNT(*)
  FROM parts p INNER JOIN odetails od
    ON p.pno = od.pno
 INNER JOIN orders o
    ON od.ono = o.ono
 INNER JOIN c1
    ON o.cno = c1.cno
 GROUP BY p.pno, p.pname;
```

By the way you should take @Strawberry's comment into consideration. Your table names are fine but your columns' names are really quite ghastly. Oracle gives you 30 characters for object names; use them. There is no reason to name a column `pno`, for example, instead of `product_id`.